# index a formatted date for full text search in both english and french

Tags: sql, postgresql, strftime

For english I do:

```sql
select to_char(starts_at, 'TMHH:MIAM DayDD MonthYYYY') from events limit 1;
             to_char              
----------------------------------
 5:40AM Saturday 18 December 2021
(1 row)
```

And then create an index with:

```sql
create index index_events_on_tsvector_english_starts_at
on events
using gin (to_tsvector('english', to_char(starts_at, 'TMHH:MIAM DayDD MonthYYYY'))
```

And I know I can do:

```
SET LC_TIME = 'fr_FR';
```

But wouldn't that not index my column in french for future rows added? (not sure)

So, how can I create an index for english and an index for french? So that my french and english speaking users can search dates with full-text search?

**Edit**: I can't create the index because my function is not immutable

```
socializus_development=#       create or replace function to_char_with_lc_time(
        expression timestamp without time zone,
        format text,
        lc_time text
      ) returns text as $$
        begin
          set LC_TIME = lc_time;
          select to_char(expression, format) as result;
          set LC_TIME = "en_US.UTF-8";
          return result;
        end;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
CREATE FUNCTION
socializus_development=# select to_char_with_lc_time(starts_at, 'FMHH24hMI TMDay DD TMMonth YYYY', 'fr_FR.UTF-8') from events limit 5;
ERROR:  SET is not allowed in a non-volatile function
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SET LC_TIME = lc_time"
PL/pgSQL function to_char_with_lc_time(timestamp without time zone,text,text) line 3 at SET
```

Comment: The format string you give doesn't depend on LC_TIME anyway.

Comment: Yes, I should have used `TM`, e.g. `TMHH:MIAM DayDD MonthYYYY`

Comment: @jjanes the weird thing is even if I do `SET LC_TIME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8';`, `select to_char(starts_at, 'TMHH:MIAM DayDD MonthYYYY') from events limit 1;` gives me an english result

Comment: You need to use `TM` before the relevant parts, like: `SET LC_TIME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'; select to_char(now(), 'TMHH:MIAM TMDayDD TMMonthYYYY');`, giving: " 07:13PM Samedi18 Décembre2021"

Comment: thanks @Luuk `select to_char(starts_at, 'FMHH24hMI TMDay DD TMMonth YYYY') from events limit 1;` gives me `5h40 Samedi 18 Décembre 2021`, and I think I need to have functions for the french/english index

Comment: Your index won't build to start with, as it complains "ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE".  But if you work around this, then yes you would need more than once index.  But doing a full text search on timestamps doesn't make much sense anyway.  Why would someone want to search on '08' and find both things on the 8th day of the month, and things during the 8th hour of the day?

Comment: Why not just use ISO Standard for all date settings and then just index the date itself. Internally the date is the same, and also for any other local as long as they use the Gregorian Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

you should not find `Wednesday` (or `Mercredi`), but find the third day of the week.

See: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=ca35356478e5185af3b16b205837f5d5)

I created a table `dow` like this:

| i | name_en | name_fr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Sunday | Dimanche |
| 1 | Monday | Lundi |
| 2 | Tuesday | Mardi |
| 3 | Wednesday | Mercredi |
| 4 | Thursday | Jeudi |
| 5 | Friday | Vendredi |
| 6 | Saturday | Samedi |

To find the next 5 Wednesday's for a Frenchman, (searching with 'Mercredi'):

```
SELECT  
    d,
    to_char(d,'TMDay'),
    to_char(d,'Day'),
    EXTRACT(DOW FROM dates.d)
FROM dates 
WHERE EXTRACT(DOW FROM dates.d) = (SELECT i FROM dow WHERE name_FR='Mercredi')
  AND d>NOW()
ORDER BY d
LIMIT 5;
```

And, YES, this is not a full text search on `Mercredi` but, I think, a quicker way to find those third days of the week.

Comment: I think I'm going to do a similar approach where I split the query in words and search, and match for words that correspond to week day names or month names, thanks